# Many-to-Many Hierarchies Relationships in SQL

Tags: sql, database, hierarchical-data

I'm trying to figure out how to store hierarchical data in a database, but I'm having trouble as the data does not seem to fit a simple tree hierarchy. I'm looking at market indices and subindices which can be divided up in multiple different ways with multiple different levels. I'll try to explain with a simple example.

Let's say we have an index representing the entire world (World) and that there are only 2 countries (USA and China). Furthermore, stocks can be divided up into only two types (Technology and Health Care). This would leave me with the following 9 indices:

```
|-------------------|---|
|Index              |ID |
|-------------------|---|
| World             | 1 |
| USA               | 2 |
| China             | 3 |
| Technology        | 4 |
| Health Care       | 5 |
| USA Technology    | 6 |
| USA Health Care   | 7 |
| China Technology  | 8 |
| China Health Care | 9 |
|-------------------|---|
```

The World index can be divided into USA and China, but it can also be divided into Technology and Health Care. Furthermore, the USA index can be divided into USA Technology and USA Health Care, while USA Health Care is also a component of Health Care (along with China Health Care).

I'd like to be able to retrieve the various different ways of grouping the indices. Here are some examples:

- Grouped by Country: { 1: [2, 3] }
- Grouped by Sector: { 1: [4, 5] }
- Grouped by Country, Sector: { 1: [2: [6, 7], 3: [8, 9]] }
- Grouped by Sector, Country: { 1: [4: [6, 8], 5: [7, 9]] }

Any suggestions on how this might be represented in relational tables?

Comment: I'd suggest drawing a boundary between your data layer and your presentation layer.  Your question seems to blend the two.  Each component should be coded with a sector and a country.  (I'd have a table of sectors, a table of countries, a table of stocks, and join tables for country and sector: this provides flexibility if a stock is listed on multiple exchanges and is in multiple sectors.)  That's it for the DAL.  For the presentation layer, you can make views that provide you with all of the desired permutations (country, sector, country-sector, sector-country, etc.)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow but I think I'm just being dense. I'm not actually trying to store any stock level data here so we can leave out the stock table. Are you saying you'd have a country table that lists just the country indices and a sector table that lists just the sector indices? What would the attributes of those tables be? And what would the join tables for country and sector look like? Thanks!

Comment: The best thing to do is consider it at _leaf_ level and just roll up from there. A given thing (stock?) might roll up in any number of ways. Given your example, you'd have a table with a list of stocks with two columns: Country and Sector. Then you split it any way you like

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to store and examine index/subindex, country, and sector relationships, then one solution involves five tables: an index table, a sector table, a sector-index join table, a country table, and a country-index join table.  The index table can hold a reference to any parent index (a self-join).  This schema obviously makes some assumptions about cardinality that you'll need to confirm.  [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6)

```
create table indices (indexid int not null primary key, name nvarchar(100), parentIndex int null,
                     foreign key (parentindex) references indices(indexid));
create table sectors (sectorid int not null primary key, name nvarchar(200));
create table countries (countryid int not null primary key, name nvarchar(200));
create table indices_join_sectors (sectorid int not null, indexid int not null,
                                  foreign key (sectorid) references sectors(sectorid),
                                  foreign key (indexid) references indices(indexid));
create table indices_join_countries (countryid int not null, indexid int not null,
                                  foreign key (countryid) references countries(countryid),
                                  foreign key (indexid) references indices(indexid));
```